# Default store view opens different store's storeview

Tags: magento-1.9

I have multi store magento 1.9 with three stores. 
I have third storeview: /en1, when I visit it with domain/en1 it opens correctly.
But when I visit domain/ (without en1), it opens first(different) store's storeview.

In this path System > Configuration > Web > Url Option > Add Store Code to Urls I've turn ON
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Forget to add default storeview to webserver configuration.
https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/magento-multistore-using-multiple-domains/#Storefronts_Websites_Store_views